# Unable to configure qemu on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu, configure

I'm trying to configure QEMU on Ubuntu 14.04 (x64):

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`configure` dies with the error message:

```
ERROR: glib-2.12 gthread-2.0 is required to compile QEMU
```

Related questions suggest to install `libc6-dev` and `build-essential`. I have `libc6-dev` and `build-essential` installed.

`config.log` is not telling me anything useful (shown below). I can't tell what test is producing that error message. The last test performed is for a bluetooth header. Prior to that, a curl header was tested.

Why is QEMU failing to configure itself?

---

```
# QEMU configure log Wed Sep 17 01:10:28 EDT 2014
# Configured with: './configure'
#
cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:2: error: #error __i386__ not defined
 #error __i386__ not defined
  ^
cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:2: error: #error __ILP32__ not defined
 #error __ILP32__ not defined
  ^
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
c++ -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.cxx config-temp/qemu-conf.o -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror -Wstring-plus-int -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wstring-plus-int’
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror -Winitializer-overrides -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Winitializer-overrides’
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror -Wendif-labels -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Werror -Wmissing-include-dirs -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Werror -Wempty-body -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Werror -Wnested-externs -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Werror -Wformat-security -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Werror -Wformat-y2k -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Werror -Winit-self -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Werror -Wignored-qualifiers -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Werror -Wold-style-declaration -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Werror -Wold-style-definition -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Werror -Wtype-limits -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Werror -fstack-protector-strong -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Werror -fstack-protector-all -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Werror -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -Werror -fno-gcse -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:4:2: error: #error No bug in this compiler.
 #error No bug in this compiler.
  ^
cc -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -fPIE -DPIE -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -m64 -g -pie
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -pie -m64 -g -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -fno-pie -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -nopie
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-nopie’
libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -c -fPIE -DPIE -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
./configure: 120: ./configure: libtool: not found
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -c -o config-temp/qemu-conf.o config-temp/qemu-conf.c
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lz
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -llzo2
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:23: fatal error: lzo/lzo1x.h: No such file or directory
 #include <lzo/lzo1x.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lsnappy
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:22: fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
 #include <snappy-c.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lxenstore -lxenctrl -lxenguest
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:21: fatal error: xenctrl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xenctrl.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lrdmacm -libverbs
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:27: fatal error: rdma/rdma_cma.h: No such file or directory
 #include <rdma/rdma_cma.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:27: fatal error: gnutls/gnutls.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gnutls/gnutls.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:27: fatal error: gnutls/gnutls.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gnutls/gnutls.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lsasl2
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sasl/sasl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -ljpeg
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jpeglib.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lpng
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
 #include <png.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
/tmp/cc9PFokH.o: In function `main':
/home/jwalton/Desktop/qemu-2.1.1/config-temp/qemu-conf.c:5: undefined reference to `uuid_generate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -luuid
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:21: fatal error: xfs/xfs.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xfs/xfs.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lvdeplug
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:24: fatal error: libvdeplug.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libvdeplug.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lcap-ng
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:20: fatal error: cap-ng.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cap-ng.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lbrlapi
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:20: fatal error: brlapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <brlapi.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lncurses
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -fstack-protector-all -o config-temp/qemu-conf.exe config-temp/qemu-conf.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:33: fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Install `libglib2.0-dev`. You'll also need `zlib1g-dev`:

```
apt-get install libglib2.0-dev zlib1g-dev
```

`./configure` should run successfully with these two and the ones you've already installed.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Sorry to bother you with it.

Comment: Bother? Isn't that the whole idea of these sites? :-)

Comment: This helps.  For recent QEMU I also had to `apt-get install libpixman-1-dev`